# Getting FullTextSqlQuery to return a permissions mask of sorts

Tags: permissions, fulltextsqlquery

I would like to have my FullTextSqlQuery return the permissions mask that the user running it has on the list items returned. Results are returned the same whether the user has Read or Contribute for example, but to me knowing that permission set would be helpful.

Would anyone know how to do this without taking each item returned from the query and going through the whole SPSite->SPWeb->SPList->SPListItem["PermMask"] mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions aren't indexed in search (there's no reason to do so, either), so the only way to get the permissions mask is exactly what you said in your question.